# Horizontal scrolling menu list while scroll menu like Uber Eats App Angular

Tags: angular, scroll, scrollspy

I would like to implement a horizontal scroll bar that has a category of the items and when u am scrolling bellow it changes as I go through the different categories. I would like to achieve this on angular for web application

I tried using bootstrap with scroll spy but it didn’t work

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share with us what you tried so that people can help you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.